# Laravel Sum on collection with duplicates data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

I have an object that consists of multiple data as `controlNumber` each `controlNumber` has `shipment.qty` what I want is to total the `qty` of each same `controlNumber` and display one `controlNumber` with total qty.

collection is below

```
"collection": [
        {
            "id": 983,
            "controlNumber": 4498818,
            "ItemNumber": "PS2W12077",
            "shipment": {
                "id": 27,
                "Item": "PS2W12077",
                "ColorCode": "GRPFR",
                "qty": 1638
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 982,
            "controlNumber": 4498818,
            "ItemNumber": "PS2W12077",
            "shipment": {
                "id": 27,
                "Item": "PS2W12077",
                "ColorCode": "GRPFR",
                "qty": 1638
            }
        },
       {
            "id": 936,
            "controlNumber": 4498815,
            "ItemNumber": "PS2T01096",
            "shipment": {
                "id": 11,
                "Item": "PS2T01096",
                "ColorCode": "MALDI",
                "qty": 1212
            }
        },
 ]
```

controlNumber `4498818` has two shipment data with two `qty` what I want is to show one `controlNumber` with total `qty` of `3276`

what I have retired is return total `qty` of all `controlNumber`

```
 $result = $collection->pipe(function ($collection) {
            return collect([
                'shipment_qty' => $collection->sum('shipment.qty'),

            ]);
        });
```

the output should be as follows

```
"collection": [
        {
            "id": 983,
            "controlNumber": 4498818,
            "ItemNumber": "PS2W12077",
            "shipment": {
                "id": 27,
                "Item": "PS2W12077",
                "ColorCode": "GRPFR",
                "qty": 3276
            }
        },
       {
            "id": 936,
            "controlNumber": 4498815,
            "ItemNumber": "PS2T01096",
            "shipment": {
                "id": 11,
                "Item": "PS2T01096",
                "ColorCode": "MALDI",
                "qty": 1212
            }
        },
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique) collection method to get only unique item based on control number value:

```
 $uniqueCollection=$collection->unique('controlNumber');

 $result=$collection2->sum(function ($item){
           return $item->shipment->qty;
       });
```

Comment: this calculate the total number of shipment qty, please look the question again

Comment: no, it calculate only unique collection rows, see fiddle in:

 https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/hyd4s?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

Comment: I have updated the question with what the output should look like @omr

Answer (score 0):

With this you get a collection where key is `controlNumber` and value is sum of `shipment->qty`.

```
$collection->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
   return [$item->controlNumber => $item->shipment->qty];
})->map->sum();
```